# pygame image to base64

Tags: python, base64, pygame

I capture screen of my pygame program like this

```
           data = pygame.image.tostring(pygame.display.get_surface(),"RGB")
```

How can I convert it into base64 string? (WITHOUT having to save it to HDD). Its important that there is no saving to HDD. I know I can save it to a file and then just encode the file to base64 but I cant seem to encode "on the fly"

thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you want, you can save it to a [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html), which is basically a virtual file stored as a string.

However, I'd really recommend using the [base64](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html) module, which has a method called `base64.b64encode`. It handles your 'on the fly' requirement well.

Code example:

```
import base64
data = pygame.image.tostring(pygame.display.get_surface(),"RGB")
base64data = base64.b64encode(data)
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah - thats what I thought originally as well. But it doesnt work. I get DIFFERENT base64 string this way when compared to creating it from file (by calling pygame.image.save()) and saving to picture file first. I get VERY LONG repetetive string the way you mentioned

Comment: looks like:(repeating 3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3djo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Ojo6Of3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//f3//

Comment: That's probably because it is raw bitmap data. GIMP can handle it if you know the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually - `pygame.image.tostring()`  is a pretty strange function (really dont understand the binary string it returns, I cant find anythin that can process it right).

There seems to be an enhancement issue on this at pygame bitbucket:
(https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/48/add-optional-format-argument-to)

I got around it like this:

```
            data = cStringIO.StringIO()
            pygame.image.save(pygame.display.get_surface(), data)
            data = base64.b64encode(data.getvalue())
```

So in the end you get the valid and RIGHT base64 string. And it seems to work. Not sure about the format yet tho, will add more info tmrw

Comment: ok, I found out this:

1. First of all <code>pygame.image.tostring()</code> provides storing into a binary string in RGB format (you can encode that in base64 and use it for other manipulation)

2. using the suggested StringIO method with <code>pygame.image.save()</code> will produce the expected string of base64 BUT it is no longer RGB - it is JPG (by default) encoded. You  can change the format in future pygame releases (see the link in this answer)

===> I ended up using pygame.image.tostring -> base64 encode -> transport over TCP -> base64 decode -> loading texture directly from bytes